WSS with Nginx cannot connect
Having issues with getting Nginx to proxy_pass with websockets and SSL (WSS).
NGINX Config
server {
    root /var/www/example.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    
   location /ws/ {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass https://example.com:9090;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
    proxy_set_header Connection Upgrade;
    proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
   }

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location = /404.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

Need help!
Error:
index.js:9 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://example.com:9090/'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.
